# How to Horizontally Center View in Landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an app that was originally written for iPhone 4s landscape mode (480x320) but when I run this in iPhone 5 simulator I see that my app is aligned to the left and there's alot of blank space to the right of it. (vertically, it looks/stretches properly)

I was hoping my app would atleast be centered in landscape mode in iPhone5, any ideas?

Also, I have another app that is in portrait mode (320x480) and in iPhone 5 is does vertically center my app properly. So is this just a problem with landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Found it in Size Inspector -> "AutoResizing".

Just had to align the red box correctly